# QtCreator stopped working when a widget added

Tags: qt-creator, qpushbutton, qframe

I alleady have 2 buttons on my frame but when I try to add 3rd button QtCreator stops working. When I try to add another frame same thing happend. Here is the sample of my code.

```
QFrame *buttonFrame = new QFrame(this);
buttonFrame->setGeometry(930,900,750,100);
buttonFrame->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);

QPushButton *nextbutton = new QPushButton(buttonFrame);
nextbutton->setText("Sonraki  ");
nextbutton->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
nextbutton->setMinimumSize(25,30);

QPushButton *downloadButton = new QPushButton(buttonFrame);
downloadButton->setText("  İndir");
downloadButton->setMinimumSize(25,30);

QPushButton *totalButton = new QPushButton(buttonFrame);
totalButton->setText("Tüm veriyi göster");
totalButton->setMinimumSize(25,40);

buttonLayout->addWidget(downloadButton,0,1);
buttonLayout->addWidget(nextbutton,0,2);
buttonLayout->addWidget(totalButton,0,3);
```

This code works perfectly when totalButton commend outed but when I try to add it inside the buttonFrame QtCreator stops working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main window was initializing fixed size that I give previously. The problem solved when I deleted fixed size feature and initalize main window default size. I hope it helped anyone who has same problem.